# How many operations can we do with an 8-digit (plus decimal) calculator?

Tags: decimal, calculator, combinatorics, operation

I have this model: a simple 8-digit display calculator (no memory buttons, no square root etc etc) has buttons (the decimal point does not count as a 'digit'):
10 buttons for integers 0 to 9, 
1 button for dot (decimal point, so it can hold decimals, like from 0.0000001 to 9999999.9), 
4 buttons for operations (+, -, /, *), and 
1 button for equality (=). (the on/off button doesn't count for this question)

The question is two-fold: how many numbers can they be represented on the calculator's screen? (a math-explained solution would be appreciated)
*AND
if we have to make all 4 basic operations between *any* pair of 2 numbers, of the above calculated, how many operations would that be?

Thank you for your insight and help!

Comment: Note: no negative numbers.

Comment: Do you count 1, 01, 1.00 etc as different numbers in your problem?

Comment: yes, integers and numbers with decimal values are been considered different. However, of course 1.0000000 and 1 are the same.

Comment: no answers/ any ideas?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part one of this answer, we want to know **how many numbers can be represented on the calculator's screen.**

Start with a simplified example and work up from there. Let's start with a 1-digit display. With this calculator, you can display the numbers from 0 to 9, and you can display each of those numbers with a decimal point either before the digit (making it a decimal), or after the digit (making it an integer). How many unique numbers can be made?

> .0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, <del>0.</del>, 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.

That's 20 possibilities with 1 repeat number makes 19 unique numbers. Let's find this result again, but using a mathematical approach that we can scale up to a larger number of digits.

Start by finding all the numbers 0 <= n < 1 that can be made. For the numbers to fit in that range, the decimal point must be before the first digit. We're still dealing with 1 digit, so there are 10<sup>1</sup> different ways to fill the calculator with numbers that are greater than or equal to 0, but less than 1.

Next, find all the numbers 1 <= n < 10 that can be made. To do this, you move the decimal point one place to the right, so now it's after the first digit, and you also can't allow the first digit to be zero (or the number will be less than 1). That leaves you 9 unique numbers.

> [0<=n<1] + [1<=n<10] = 10 + 9 = 19

Now we have a scaleable system. Let's do it with 2 digits so you see how it works with multiple digits before we go to 8 digits. With 2 digits, we can represent 0-99, and the decimal point can go in three different places, which means we have three ranges to check: 0<=n<1, 1<=n<10, 10<=n<100. The first set can have zero in its first place, since zero is in the set, but every other set can't have zero in the first place or else the number would be in the set below it. So the first set has 10<sup>2</sup> possibilities, but each of the other sets has 9 * 10<sup>1</sup> possibilities. We can generalize this by saying that for any number ***d*** of digits that our calculator can hold, the set 0<=n<1 will have 10<sup>d</sup> possibilities, and each other set will have 9 * 10<sup>d-1</sup> possibilities

So for 2 digits:

> [0<=n<1] + [1<=n<10] + [10<=n<100] = 100 + 90 + 90 = 280

Now you can see a pattern emerging, which can be generalize to give us the total amount of unique numbers that can be displayed on a calculator with ***d*** digits:

> Unique displayable numbers = 10<sup>d</sup> + d * 9 * 10<sup>d-1</sup>

You can confirm this math with a simple Python script that manually finds all the unique numbers that can be displayed, prints the quantity it found, then also prints the result of the formula above. It gets bogged down when it gets to higher numbers of digits, but digits 1 through 5 should be enough to show the formula works.

```py
for digits in range(1, 6):
    print('---%d Digits----' % digits)
    numbers = set()
    for d in range(digits + 1):
        numbers.update(i / 10**d for i in range(10**digits))
    print(len(set(numbers)))
    print(10**digits + digits * 9 * 10**(digits - 1))
```

And the result:

> ---1 Digits----
>   19
>   19
>   ---2 Digits----
>   280
>   280
>   ---3 Digits----
>   3700
>   3700
>   ---4 Digits----
>   46000
>   46000
>   ---5 Digits----
>   550000
>   550000

Which means that **a calculator with an 8 digit display can show 820,000,000 unique numbers.**

For part two of this answer, we want to know **if we have to make all 4 basic operations between any pair of 2 numbers, of the above calculated, how many operations would that be?**

How many pairs of numbers can we make between 820 million unique numbers? 820 million squared. That's 672,400,000,000,000,000 = 672.4 quadrillion. Four different operations can be used on these number pairs, so multiply that by 4 and you get **2,689,600,000,000,000,000 = 2.6896 quintillion different possible operations on a simple 8 digit calculator.**

**EDIT:**

If the intention of the original question was for a decimal point to not be allowed to come before the first digit (a decimal 0<=n<1 would have to start with ***0.***) then the formula for displayable numbers changes to **10<sup>d</sup> + (d - 1) * 9 * 10<sup>d-1</sup>**, which means the amount of **unique displayable numbers is 730 million** and the **total number of operations is 2.1316 quintillion**.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. I end up with a different number, so I am trying to follow your logic - I might be wrong. Below my method.

Comment: For 1 digit place, I can represent 9 decimals (0.1-0.9) and 9 natural integers (1-9), so this means for [1] place, I can represent 18 + 1 (the zero) = 19 numbers.
For 2 digit places, I can represent 90 decimal numbers, from 0.1 to (and including) 10, and then another 89 integer numbers, from (and including) 11 to 99, because at that range I don't have any place for decimals. This means for [2] places, I can represent 90 decimal numbers and 99 integer numbers + 1 for zero, meaning 190 numbers.

Comment: So calculating how many decimal numbers and how many integer numbers I can represent at each state (i.e. for [1] digit place, for [2] digits places, for [3] digits places etc), I end up calculating that:

The decimal numbers I can "hold" per place are (9*digits-1)*[10^(digits-1)] where "digits" are the places I have to my disposal to represent numbers, and this holds for digits > 1.

Comment: For example, if I have 3 digits, I can represent (9*3-1)*(10^3-1) = (9*2)*(10^2) = 18*100 = 1800 decimal numbers. This is true, the numbers we can represent with 3 digits in our disposal, are 990 decimal numbers from 0.01 to (and including) 10, then 810 decimal numbers from 10.1 to (and including) 100, and then after 100 we cannot represent any decimal number because we need all 3 digits for integers.
So we end up with 990 + 810 = 1800 decimal numbers. Obviously with 3 digits we can have 1000 integers (999 numbers plus zero) so this brings the total positive numbers we can represent to 2800.

Comment: Following the above logic I calculated:
[1] = 9 decimals numbers, and 10 naturals including 0, total 19 numbers.
[2] = d(90), n(99) +1 (for zero) = 190
[3] = d(1,800), n(999) +1 = 2,800
[4] = d(27,000), n(9,999) +1 = 370,000
[5] = d(360,000), n(99,999) +1 = 460,000
and so on and so forth.

Comment: Arriving at eight digits places, I end up with
[8] = d(630,000,000), n(99,999,999) +1 = 730,000,000
And I agree with you, I think for pairwise selection we raise to power of 2 so, 730,000,000^2 = 532,900,000,000,000,000.
And then with this number multiplied by 4, I end up with
 2,131,600,000,000,000,000 
which is quite close to your result..
I couldn't find the error, maybe when you have time you see the calculations and discover the truth.
Thank you again very much for your effort !!!

Comment: Note: I did not calculated the first numbers who have decimals but no integer part (I am referring to number with mantissa having a 0 as characteristic, i.e. 0.01). So, in a calculator, we would need an extra digit, the zero digit as characteristic.
If you assume that we may represent [dot][zero][one] .01 (and safely occupy two places) instead of [zero][dot][zero][one], i.e. 0.01 (which requires three places), I think this could be the error. Well, maybe.

Comment: As for me: I see in your table for 2 digits you represent 280 numbers.
However:
For [2] digits places, I see I can represent decimal numbers 0.1-0.9, 1.1-1.9, 2.1-2.9 ... 9.1-9.9 and these are 90 decimals numbers. Adding 100 integers (1-99 plus the 0) this means for 2 digit places we can represent 190 numbers.
I think my logic holds, but please confirm..

Comment: Our math is completely complementary, and your obvservation of me counting decimals with mantissa value == 0 is exactly where our answers differ. In my understanding of the problem, a leading zero before the decimal point wasn’t required, so the answer I present allows for numbers which are entirely decimal (ex. .12345678). If the decimal point can’t come before a first digit I think your math is good and your answer is correct.

Comment: The only inconsistency I see with your logic is in your second comment, when you say that with 1 digit you can represent 19 numbers. Because all of the decimals with 1 digit have no integer part. Holding to your requirements, with 1 digit you could only make 10 numbers. However, the formula you propose in comment three supports the 1 digit = 10 numbers conclusion, so your overall results hold true

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your time on this and your comment. They are all very valuable to me. Much, much appreciated.

Comment: I added an edit to the answer to match your results